# Lasso select not working, but box select is?

Tags: selection-tools

For some reason - randomly - I am no longer able to lasso select objects in my scene.

See below gif:

[image: gif]

I am able to box select, but not lasso. I've checked that my objects are selectable in the outline panel. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong - or how this even happened to begin with.

Any thoughts are appreciated

EDIT

I currently have "Select Box" chosen as my selection method, and do CTRL+RMB for lasso. Though, I get the same issue with lasso not working regardless of which selection method I choose (including lasso)

[image]

Comment: What selection tool are you using?

Comment: I am using "Select Box" but do Ctrl+RMB to do a lasso select, which was working for days but randomly stopped? am I doing something wrong? ADDED EDIT TO OP

Answer (score 2):

### **Use the Tweak tool**

*Disclaimer: I'm a right click selecter. I don't know if there is any difference if you joined the left clikers army.*

Since 2.80 version, lasso and box select shortcuts by default only works when the Tweak tool is active (see the keymap first column below).

[image]

Box and lasso select tool I think are made for early adopters to make sure to have simple select tools like the would find to expect in other software packages (photoshop...)

Back in the days (<2.79) we didn't had "selection tools" and we just used shortcuts. Tweak tool mimic that situation. I made that my default tool.

Comment: i appreciate the response but this didnt work for me..i dont really have an answer but seems like i had a ridiculous amount of objects (>500K objects w/ 10-20verts and maybe 10 or so faces each) and things just started bugging out after a while lol

Comment: Have you tried to delete some of the object just to see if it works with a simpler scene?

Comment: It definitely works with a previous version of the file before I added more objects and works in every other blend file I have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the origin point (that little orange dot that can usually sit at the world origin) of the mesh in your selection. So you need to lasso select around the mesh and also its origin point.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think, it's deffinitely question about selecting origins of meshes while using lasso. So, I've selected all meshes and chose in menu Object/Set Origin/Origin to geometry and then I can select by lasso.